# How to set a MQ Transport in Oracle Service Bus Console?

Tags: weblogic, ibm-mq, osb, transport

I need to set a **MQ Transport provider** to be able to use it in different services that there has been created previously. 
The idea it's to **migrate some services** between ***version 11g to 12c*** **Oracle Service Bus**. I know that i could some of the same
by using the MQAdapter but isn't the idea that is required with these services.
By trying to upload these service without the setting it brings me an alert in the logs about 'There's no **mq transport provider**
set nor configured' something like that .

[Error with mq Provider not found - Click to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwpLf.png)

Someone could help me or give me a hint with that? ,

Comment: Is this related to IBM MQ?

Comment: Maybe, the deal it's that the destiny it's a IBM MQ Server who is given us all the details, I would say it's more OSB related, firstly. By the way the classic behavior error code 2035 in IBM MQ how could be avoided ?, I'm using for testing purpose a local MQ Server and at the same time I'm trying to use it from the same account i read some about that members admin from mqm can use directly their objects from an external App, can be avoid these rules for test purpose?, thanks JoshMC.

Comment: What does the `AMQERR01.LOG` show at the time of the 2035. There can be many causes, such as you using a `SYSTEM.*` channel, or coming in as a ADMIN  user, or no permission to a queue.

Comment: Boths  I'm using a System.* channel and an ADMIN user, I've already changed the user and i'll try again modifying the access files for the admin channel making available request per System channel because these are only test samples, just for educational purposes, I know it's a bad practice but it's functional for the reason that I'm using it, Thanks JoshMc for your time, we can closed this thread here. All the best.